# Angular 6 how to set the return type of a promise from observer

Tags: angular, typescript, http, promise

I'm usually one for observable's but to prevent 'callback hell' in this scenario i'm using `toPromise()` on it for ease but i am getting the lint error message when trying to define the return type:

> The 'Object' type is assignable to very few other types. Did you mean to use the 'any' type instead?   Type 'Object' is missing the
>   following properties from type 'ReferralReasons[]': length

my code (`this.apiSvc.get` returns the http.get object):

```
async getJobReferralReasons(): Promise<Array<ReferralReasons>> {
    return this.apiSvc.get(`${this.API_JOB}/ReferralReasons`).toPromise();
}
```

but this is fine without the error:

```
async getJobReferralReasons(): Promise<any> {
    return this.apiSvc.get(`${this.API_JOB}/ReferralReasons`).toPromise();
}
```

So then when calling it i get the array of referral codes outright in an array:

```
const reasons = await this.helpdeskSvc.getJobReferralReasons();
```

I would have thought that changing `any` and setting the type `Array<ReferralReasons>` would work, what am i missing to set the correct type?

---Update

My service call looks like this:

```
get(apiURL, data = {}) {
    return this.http.get(this.parseURL(apiURL), {
        headers: this.getHeaders(),
        params: this.parseGetParams(data)
    });
}
```

But this works but it's not what i have (as you can see it's slightly different and i can't put the type before the get):

```
async getJobReferralReasons2(): Promise<ReferralReasons[]> {
    return this.http.get<ReferralReasons[]>('', {}).toPromise();
}
```

Comment: Can you make a real scenario of the error in StackBlitz? What *ashish.gd* said should work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to update your http `get` call with the expected **return type** for the `promise` to recognise it.

Example:

**apiSvc** using `T` template for type.

```js
get<T>(apiURL, data = {}) {
  return this.http.get<T>(this.parseURL(apiURL), {
      headers: this.getHeaders(),
      params: this.parseGetParams(data)
  });
}
```

**component** using actual type

```js
async getJobReferralReasons(): Promise<Array<ReferralReasons>> {
    return this.apiSvc.get<Array<ReferralReasons>>(`${this.API_JOB}/ReferralReasons`).toPromise();
}
```

OR

```js
async getJobReferralReasons(): Promise<ReferralReasons[]> {
    return this.apiSvc.get<ReferralReasons[]>(`${this.API_JOB}/ReferralReasons`).toPromise();
}
```

Comment: The IDE doesn't seem to like either syntax and complains saying 'Expected 0 type arguments, but got 1.'

Comment: Have you wrapped `httpClient's` get method in your `apiSvc` ?

Comment: Updated the answer. The `get` method should accept a template type. Now you can provide the actual type when calling the `get` method from your component.

Comment: Perfect the <T> did the trick - i learned something new today, thanks!